# Contravariance in Kotlin in sortedWith() extension function

Tags: kotlin, generics

In Kotlin sortedWith extension is defined with contravariance for Comparator:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): List<T>
```

To my understanding this is to enable to use Comparator of a super type to compare actual types:

```
val comparator: Comparator<Number> = Comparator { o1: Number, o2: Number ->
      o1.toInt().compareTo(o2.toInt())
}
val intList: List<Int> = listOf(4, 7)
intList.sortedWith(comparator)
```

But this would also work without introducing contravariance:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWithMock(comparator: Comparator<T>) {
}

val comparator: Comparator<Number> = Comparator { o1: Number, o2: Number ->
     o1.toInt().compareTo(o2.toInt())
}
val intList: List<Int> = listOf(4, 7)
intList.sortedWithMock(comparator)
```

Am I missing something, or contravariant declaration is not really needed in sortWith()?

In Java the <? super E> is needed to compile the related snipped:

```
public class Test {
 
    // Comparator<? super E> required
    static <E> void sort(List<E> l, Comparator<E> c) {
        
    }
    
    static class cn implements Comparator<Number> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Number o1, Number o2) {
            return 0;
       } 
    }
        
    public static void main(String []args){
          List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          Comparator<Number> cn = new cn();
          sort(l, cn);
    }
}
```

Seems that Kotlin compiler does the required contravariant conversion by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contravariance of the `Comparator` allows the function to return a `List<T>` where `T` was the original type of your `List`, not the type of the `Comparator`.

If you flesh out your mock function to return `List<T>`, then when you call the function using a `Comparator<Number>`, the type `T` will be `Number`, not `Int`, so your returned `List` type is less specific than the original `Iterable`. This is because to call your mock function, it must implicitly up-cast the `Iterable`'s covariant type to a type that matches the `Comparator`'s invariant type.

Instead, the standard library function is able to implicitly down-cast the `Comparator`'s contravariant type to match the `Iterable's` type.